# insert large data to database using dataset

Tags: c#, insert, dataset, large-data

How to insert about 300 record from dataset into database?
It takes so long about 5 minute
I want to know is there any way to improve the process using dataset?

edit:
this is my code, when user klik sav, it will do the following process:

```
public void ProcessSkalaGaji(MyDataSet myDataSet, DateTime tanggalBerlaku, decimal percentage)
{
   GenerateNewSkalaGaji(myDataSet, tanggalBerlaku, percentage);
   InsertSkalaGaji(myDataSet);
}

private void GenerateNewSkalaGaji(MyDataSet myDataSet, DateTime tanggalBerlaku, decimal percentage)
{
   // GetLastSkalaGaji returns about 300 rows
   MyDataSet.SkalaGajiDataTable skalaGajiTable = GetLastSkalaGaji();

   foreach (MyDataSet.SkalaGajiRow skalaGajiRow in skalaGajiTable.Rows)
   {
      MyDataSet.SkalaGajiRow newSkalaGajiRow = myDataSet.SkalaGaji.NewSkalaGajiRow();
      newSkalaGajiRow.TanggalBerlaku = tanggalBerlaku;
      newSkalaGajiRow.Golongan = skalaGajiRow.Golongan;
      newSkalaGajiRow.MasaKerja = skalaGajiRow.MasaKerja;
      newSkalaGajiRow.GajiPokok = skalaGajiRow.GajiPokok + (skalaGajiRow.GajiPokok * percentage / 100);

      myDataSet.SkalaGaji.AddSkalaGajiRow(newSkalaGajiRow);
   }
}

private string InsertSkalaGaji(MyDataSet myDataSet)
{
   string errorMsg = string.Empty;

   if (myDataSet.HasChanges() && !myDataSet.HasErrors)
   {
      int rowsAffected = Adapter.Update(myDataSet.SkalaGaji);

      if (rowsAffected == 0)
      {
         errorMsg = "No rows inserted! Please contact your administrator";
      }
   }

   return errorMsg;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Post some code so we can detect where to optimize

Comment: 300 actually means 3M or why have you mentioned _large_? You should also mention the sql and the table schema. Are you using transactions?

Comment: 1 second per record?. Post some code.

Comment: normally a dataset wouldn't take long to insert it into the DB. Especially not when it's only 300 rows. So yes, as Agustin Meriles said, if you could paste in some code would be helpfull.

Comment: @tim: what should i call? sorry about my bad english :)

I already edit the question, thanks for you attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SqlBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class to efficiently copy data to your database.

```
var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(yourConnection);
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.YourTable";
var table = GetLastSkalaGaji();
bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);
```

Comment: Thanks RePierre, it could be alternative

Answer (score 0):

I've just found the solution, when method InsertSkalaGaji called, before Adapter.Update(myDataSet.SkalaGaji) I create a new SkalaGajiDataTable that contain only inserted rows

code:

```
MyDataSet.SkalaGajiDataTable newSkalaGaji = (MyDataSet.SkalaGajiDataTable)
myDataSet.SkalaGaji.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added);

int rowsAffected = Adapter.Update(newSkalaGaji);
```

and to insert about 300 records, it only takes 4 seconds
Thanks all